# Commenting variables in RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

Oftentimes, I am a bit confused with the identification of my variables in R (RStudio, to be specific), even if I try to give descriptive names. It would be nice to assign labels or hints to them, but it doesn't seem to be possible in RStudio. Is there a handy solution?

Comment: for example you can create df with 2 colums `var_name`,`comment`. and then use `df$comment[df$var_name=="neededvar"]` or write simple fucntion for it

Comment: Why not use `#` and add your descriptive comments to your variable/  every line of code, explaining what it does ?

Comment: Or check out sth like `comment(myvar) <- "description"; attr(myvar, "mycomment") <- "and another description"; comment(myvar); myvar`

Comment: `comment()` seems appropriate, thanks (but originally I thought something visible right in RStudio's Environment window over the variable).

Comment: Perhaps this wld be a good feature request to @kevinushey. It prbly wldn't be that hard to add it as a field in the environment inspector.

Answer (score 0):

There are several R coding conventions on the web that contain suggestions for good variable names and ccode commenting practices. See [google's style guidelines](https://google.github.io/styleguide/Rguide.xml) or [wickham's style guide](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Style.html) among others.